# Curve fitting for 16 coefficients Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting, discrete-mathematics

I found equation  for my project in the [link](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FHesham_Rakha%2Fpublication%2F228386009_Emission_model_development_using_in-vehicle_on-road_emission_measurements%2Flinks%2F0fcfd51071e23d8955000000.pdf&ei=Mm7CVNq3OozXPKvkgPgK&usg=AFQjCNFvgo-ilKZivZGUX1L05reQIv2KMA&bvm=bv.84349003,d.ZWU) (page 8) like this:

[image]

The equation uses double summation, hence I get 16 terms over the exponential place and how can I fit this for my data using MATLAB to find the 16 coefficients ranging from L00 to L33 (In one case).
If I  could understand one case (say a>0), I can do the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fitlm(X,y) function where X is all your 16 terms from u^0*a^0 to u^3*a^3 and y is your MOE of the equation.

Then the output will be the coefficients, i.e., L00 to L33, you want.

Comment: Sorry I just made a mistake on, L00 to L33 are your coefficients. What you need to do is first compute all the 16 combinations of u^i and a^j, i.e., their products, then use them as X in the function.